# How do you access a Marketo Token in Velocity script

Tags: velocity, marketo

I'm creating an email in Marketo that is sent when a new article is posted on my website and contains a section at the bottom for a related article as well. The article and related article information are set up automatically using tokens (they are triggered via an API call).

I want to hide the related article section if there is no related article present. This seems like something that should be done via a Script token. However, I can't figure out how to access token data (e.g. `{{my.related_post_headline}}`) from within my script token. Is this possible? If not, what is the best practice for having dynamic content based on token data?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it is not possible to read Program Tokens using Marketo's Velocity Scripting. You can read data from Lead fields and from Custom Objects.

Keep in mind that Velocity Scripting is relatively slow, so it may delay your email send for large volumes (it has to execute the script for each email). You can use [Head Start](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Head+Start+for+Email+Programs?src=search&src=search) if you're using an Email Program, which will pre-process the Velocity Script.

Alternatively, you could choose NOT to use Velocity Scripting and insert Lead Tokens or Program Tokens directly into the email. This will speed up email rendering.

Comment: If I can't read the token in Velocity, is it possible to change whether a section of an email is rendered based on the value of a token? For example, if I pass a token `related_post_rendered` with a value of `"true"`, can I use that to display the entire section of the email? I'm trying to avoid sending entire content blocks via tokens